# ZeroMQ bind API zmq_bind() to 127.0.0.1:5555 returns error 19

Tags: sockets, zeromq

I am learning ZeroMQ for which I tried to bind it to local host as follows:

```
void* m_zmqContext;
void* m_zmqSocket;

m_zmqContext = zmq_ctx_new();
unsigned int error_code = zmq_errno();
printf("server ctx error: %u, %s\n", error_code, zmq_strerror(error_code));

m_zmqSocket = zmq_socket(m_zmqContext, ZMQ_REP);
error_code = zmq_errno();
printf("server socket error: %u, %s\n", error_code, 
zmq_strerror(error_code));

zmq_bind(m_zmqSocket, "tcp://127.0.0.1:5555");
error_code = zmq_errno();
printf("server bind error: %u, %s\n", error_code, zmq_strerror(error_code));
```

This produces output as:

```
server ctx error: 0, No error
server socket error: 0, No error
server bind error: 19, No such device
```

An output from `netstat -aon | find /i "listening"` does not show any process using the port `5555`.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> **Q** : *"How to resolve this issue?"*

**Step 0 :**
Proof of having a device at hand :

```
~$ traceroute 127.0.0.1 --tos=8    \
                        --port=5555 \
                        --queries=9  \
                        --sendwait=9
            
traceroute to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  localhost (127.0.0.1)  0.030 ms  0.027 ms  0.026 ms  0.028 ms  0.027 ms  0.028 ms  0.024 ms  0.028 ms  0.026 ms
```

<kbd>ON FAIL</kbd> : self evident

---

<kbd>ON PASS</kbd> : file an incident at ZeroMQ maintainers, documenting all respective platform state/details, incl. the ZeroMQ version used, best with your error-reproducible code.

Comment: @RKum how did the **[Step 0]** result, Sir? Problem solved? Do not hesitate to post the dichotomy results to the benefit of the Community.